# On click, bring element to the top of the window (with offset)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to click this button, which is a section head of an accordion and have it move to the top of page (based on window)

I feel like this is simple --- but it was a long day. Any ideas?

Some background is that this is an accordion like thing - and the buttons are headers. Because the accordion is long - and the phone screen is small --- when you fold and open... you can end up in some random middle area of a section and I'm trying to get that section to move to the top instead of a hash... I've tried a few hash ideas, but I'll also need an if statement to avoid this happening on larger screens. I hope that is clear. Thanks. OH and [HERE is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/X4g6Y/)

HTML

```
<div class="some-div"></div>

<div class="some-div"></div>

<button>button to endup up at top</button>

<div class="some-div"></div>
<div class="some-div"></div>

<div class="some-div"></div>

<div class="some-div"></div>

<div class="some-div"></div>
<div class="some-div"></div>

<div class="some-div"></div>

<button>button to endup up at top</button>
```

javascript

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this). go-to-the-top-with-an-offset-of-10px();  
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this, you can move at the top of the page ("based on window"):

```
$('button').click(function() {   // on button click
    $("html, body").animate({    // catch the `html, body`
        scrollTop:0              // make their `scrollTop` property 0, to go at the top
    }, 1000);                    // in 1000 ms (1 second)
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/X4g6Y/1/)

Or if you want to move up by an offset of 10px, use:

```
$('button').click(function () { // on button click
    $("html, body").animate({ // catch the `html, body`
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 10 // button's offset - 10 
    }, 1000); // in 1000 ms (1 second)
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/X4g6Y/3/)

Or let's say you want to bring the 8th div to the top on click, use:

```
$('button').click(function () { // on button click
    $("html, body").animate({ // catch the `html, body`
        scrollTop: $("div:nth-of-type(8)").offset().top // 8th div's top offset
    }, 1000); // in 1000 ms (1 second)
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/X4g6Y/4/)

Comment: My situation became more complicated! But this got me back on track. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer helped me tremendously today. Thank you!

Comment: @RachelS Welcome :)